# Pineapple open face chinese Initial layout

Tags: open-face-chinese

I've been practicing different layouts of hands trying to get better. I am unsure of the best setup for this starting hand:

Q:hearts:Q:diamonds:J:diamonds:8:clubs:6:spades:

I want to put the Queens up top to go for fantasyland. This complicates things on the middle and bottom hands.

**Setup 1**

Q:hearts:Q:diamonds:

8:clubs:6:spades:

J:diamonds:

This setup tends to work ok if the first three cards contains cards above the 8s and 6s as two can be placed on the bottom and now you can shoot for two pair hands on the middle and bottom.

This setup tends to foul if you catch 9s, 7s, and 5s early. Placing them in the middle sets up for a straight, but now you are way behind on the bottom. Making a higher straight or full house with 9 cards to come is difficult.

**Setup 2**

Q:hearts:Q:diamonds:

J:diamonds:

8:clubs:6:spades:

This setup alleviates the problems with catching 9s 7s and 5s early as they can be played on bottom and the chase for a straight is on. It introduces issues when catching high cards or pairs such as 3s or 4s in the first three cards. 3s in the middle are problematic when you catch Js, As, Ks next. The J is almost unplayable center in this scenario as Js and 3s two pair is tough to beat with the 86 on bottom.

I suspect this is the best initial play, but it misses fantasyland more:

**Setup 3**

Blank top

8:clubs:6:spades:

Q:hearts:Q:diamonds:J:diamonds:

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It probably doesn't help that not many people know what Pineapple Open Face Poker is, so here's a link.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-face_Chinese_poker

My own opinion, which I use whenever I get really stuck on a problem, is to start out with the strongest and end with the weakest, hoping we will never get there. So I woud choose setup 2.